# ASP.NET Core MVC project fails to load assembly

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm building a website using ASP.NET Core MVC. I have a problem and don't know how to solve it.

I've created a separate project (.Net Core Library) and implemented some methods in it to use in the main project. I've added the library to my ASP.NET Core MVC project and tried to call a method inside a controller.

I've used a try catch block and noticed that when it hits the library code, it throws this exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Both projects target the .NET Core 2.2 framework.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` explicitly in your web application? It's referenced implicitly in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` metapackage which uses [implicit versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implicit-versioning)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was opned in [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6357#issuecomment-388380899) please try the suggested solutions